# Closing as Offtopic: "Should be on StackOverflow"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add Stack Overflow as a migration option in the off-topic vote-to-close dialog](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/446/please-add-stack-overflow-as-a-migration-option-in-the-off-topic-vote-to-close-di)

When voting to close as Offtopic, we have the option to say "**should be on meta**".  Other sites, such as Programmers, additionally have a "**should be on StackOverflow**" option.  Since we get so many dev questions here that should be moved, is it possible for us to get this option?  Or is that something that "needs" to wait until we're out of beta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is listed there because we are in beta.

Once we're out of beta we'll get a set of migration paths based on where we've already sent questions. I'm sure Stack Overflow will be one of them. The ***vast*** majority of questions migrated away have been to SO. I only see one each to ui.stackexchange.com and programmers.stackexchange.com.

(Diamond mods can migrate questions to any site in the network.)

***Update***: I have made a [feature request](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/446/267) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the feature request.