# Please add Stack Overflow as a migration option in the off-topic vote-to-close dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

The ***vast*** majority of off-topic questions that we've migrated away have been to Stack Overflow. (In fact, I only see two questions migrated to a site *other* than SO.)

Please add Stack Overflow to the potential list of target sites when voting to close for being off-topic.

***Edit***: Stack Overflow continues to be, by far, where most of the questions migrated away from here go. It would be *really* useful to have Stack Overflow as a default migration option.

***Edit 2***: This trend continues. This would be *really* useful to have.

Comment: Who's capable of making this change, and how do we get their attention?

Comment: The devs. And tagging with "feature-request" should be enough. They do monitor all of the child metas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A migration path to Stack Overflow is now enabled.

Comment: +1000000 (if I could)

Comment: +1, i'm with Al.

Comment: THANK YOU[.](http://blanklink.foo/) :D